# iOS: Blank Screen after Splash and Login

Tags: ios, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am building this mobile app using Nativescript & angular. It was working fine till we recently added webpack to the mix in order to speed up startup time. It worked for both platforms till we noticed the iOS has this weird bug.

Its screen just goes blank/white after login. No errors outputted. Android works fine.

UPDATE: After much debugging, turns out the issue is being caused by the Nativescript's SideDrawer component (RadSideDrawer). Anytime, it is commented out, the screen shows as expected but the sidebar is obviously scattered but once it's uncommented, we have WSOD.

Comment: You should look into the things which you are doing after “appdidfinishlaunching”

Comment: What exactly you have after login? Where it suppose to go? All you modules are lazily loaded?

Comment: Yes, they are. After login is the home/dashboard view. There is a sidebar and it seems the issue is from NativeScript's RadSideDrawer component. The WSOD only occurs when it is uncommented :-(

Comment: which version of {NS} and sidedrawer are you using?